# Matplotlib's mPlot3d cuts out part of the plot's background

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I'm trying to save a 3d graph in *.png*, but the white-colored background of the plot isn't large enough to fit the z-axis indexes.
The same problem doesn't show with *.jpg* since it automatically fills transparent background with white.

[PNG Generated plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNBWp.png)
(Actually, imgur also fills the background, but you can see the fill on the right because it's gray-shaded).

The code I'm using is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# PLOTTING
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5.0, 5.0])
ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis)
plt.savefig('fig_NablaBsing.png', bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

EDIT:

After some testing I'm pretty sure that this is a bug.
Matplotlib's `figure()` documentation says that the `facecolor` property is set to `white` by default, but this seems to not be the case.

Instead, I get the correctly rendered plot only when I manually add `facecolor='white'` either to `figure()` or to `savefig()`.

Comment: I tried your code and for me it works just fine. Which version of matplotlib are you using? You can drop the auto_add_to_figure as it is deprecated anyways.

Comment: I'm using version: 3.4.1.
I dropped the auto_add but the results are the same. I'm executing the code in JupyterLab notebook by the way.

Comment: Is it possible that the code works fine for you because you're using a pic viewer that automatically fills transparent background with white? In that case you wouldn't notice the problem, but it would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround.
I've added to savefig() the property:

```
facecolor='white'
```

This seems to fix the transparency bug of *.png* files.
If someone knows a better way to fix this, maybe the correct way instead of working around the problem, please post it as an answer.

EDIT: There's also another way to fix the bug by setting `facecolor='white'` in `figure()`.